# File Formats Supported by UIWEBVIEW in ios 6.0

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I need to find the list of file formats supported by uiwebview from ios 6.0 so that i can ignore the unsupported formats.

Comment: Is xlsx format supported in uiwebview?

Comment: the doc i linked says `xls` is, but there is no mention of xslx

Comment: @justin Thanks for the link...It refers to formats supported in ios 3.0....Any new formats are supported?Im getting crashes when i try to open some xlsx documents...not all....Why is this inconsistency?

Comment: I'd assume they have not added new formats since then; that the doc is up to date. doesn't it work if you save it in a supported format, such as xls? if not, maybe console messages can guide you. i'd just start with a supported format.

Comment: Got it.I was trying to work with unsupported formats like odt,xlsx etc  so i was getting an uneven response with such documents.Many of them were displaying correctly while some files tends to crash.

Comment: Any idea on the video formats supported by UIWebview?

Comment: try ".mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the latest list:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apples documentation...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749